# Why is my Index was out of range in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've tried to create some list with increase number after some calculation each month for a year. 
For example, in month 1 `number = 1`, month 2 `number = 3`, month 3 `number = 5`. 
The calculation is like this `number[i] = i + number[i - 1]`. Which `i` is the month.

I want to show all the list like this

```
Month[1] = 1,
Month[2] = 3,
Month[3] = 5,
Month[4] = 7,
Month[5] = 9,
Month[6] = 11,
Month[7] = 13,
...
Month[12] = 23
```

Here's my Controller

```
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    List<int> number = new List<int>();
    if (i <= 12)
    {
        number[i] = a(i, number[i - 1]); 
    }
    else 
    {
        //something else
    }
}
```

Here's my `a` function

```
public int a(int month, int number)
{
    try
    {
        a = month + number;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return a;
}
```

But, when executed i'm getting this error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

I've change the controller into this

```
for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
{
    //...
}
```

But have the same error. Can someone help me? Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Because `List<int> number = new List<int>();` initializes an empty collection so `number[i]` throwsan exception because there are not items in it (and what is the point of `if (i <= 12)`? - its always less that 12)

Comment: @StephenMuecke if I change into `List<int>[] number = new List<int>[13];` I'm getting this error `the best overloaded method match for...has some invalid arguments` in my `number[i] = a(i, number[i - 1]); `

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really new using MVC, still learning.

Comment: What is the actual output your trying to achieve? (list out all 12 values you expect)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, all of the values...

Comment: No I mean edit you question with what you want the final values in the collection to be - 1, 3, 5, what comes next etc? (its hard to understand what your trying to achieve from the code you have shown)

Comment: Try moving the list declaration outside your loop, also it's likely you need `i < 12` and not `i <= 12` when starting from `i = 0` Also - your first iteration of `i = 0` will provide a negative index of -1 (`number[0 - 1]`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Edited my question...

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Isn't it mean that would be start from `Month[0] = -1`, but I want to start from `Month[1] = 1`, `Month[2] = 3`, ..., `Month[12] = 23` is that possible?

Comment: @JTR, you could simply do that with `int x = 1; for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { number.Add(i + n); x++; }`

Comment: Use number.Add your issue will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Fiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ptZPRh)

```
int[] number = new int[13];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            if (i <= 12)
            {
                number[i] = a(i, number[i - 1]);
            }
            else
            {
                //something else
            }
        }
        int j = 1;
        List<int> item = new List<int>();
        foreach (var a in number)
        {
            if (j <= 12)
            {
                item.Add(a);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }

   public int a(int month, int number)
    {
        int a = 0;
        try
        {
            a = month + number;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: ?? That does not even come close the the output OP is wanting.

Comment: its taking time to load the result... [FYI check this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DdU13.jpg) .. it wil be more clear for you

Comment: It was clear to be before. Compare the result you get with the values OP has stated in the question.